# Problema no código provavelmente proveniente do SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, .net, string

Estou tentando criar um sistema de login bem simples, sou novo na programação e ainda estou aprendendo e me deparei com um erro, o compilador não apresenta nenhum erro porem ao executar e tentar efetuar o login mesmo com dados certo ou mesmo errado ao clicar no botão acessar ele apresenta esse erro.
essa é minha primeira pergunta então se esqueci de algo por favor me corrijam e peçam.

[image: imagem com o codigo do erro]
Já modifiquei a string de varias maneiras porem o erro persiste, o serviço do SqlServver esta em execução corretamente e a principio conectado ao visual studio. 
segue o código pra ver se vcs conseguem me ajudar.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace TesteDeLogin3
{
    public partial class TelaDeLoguin1 : Form
    {
        public TelaDeLoguin1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnsair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnacessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-LHJNB75;Initial Catalog=BancoDeLogin;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*)  *From Table where usuario=' " + txbuser.Text + "' and senha ='" + txbsenha.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();

                TelaDeEntrada ss = new TelaDeEntrada();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor verifique as informaçoes digitadas e tente novamente");
            }
        }

        private void TelaDeLoguin1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.bancoDeLoginDataSet.Table);

        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Experimenta tirar o `*` que está colado no `From`. Ao invés de **`*From`**, será **`From`**

Comment: Fiz a modificação mas o erro continua

Answer (score 1):

A sua query está incorreta:

`SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*)  *From Table where usuario=' " + txbuser.Text + "' and senha ='" + txbsenha.Text + "'", con);`

O correto seria:

`SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Table where usuario=' " + txbuser.Text + "' and senha ='" + txbsenha.Text + "'", con);`

Comment: Obrigado, mas fiz a correção e mesmo assim apresente o mesmo erro ainda

Answer (score 0):

Conforme foi respondido sua query esta com um * a mais, acredito que poderia utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT COUNT(1) From Table WHERE usuario='{txbuser.Text}' and senha ='{txbsenha.Text}'", con)
```